# Flutter Show a toast message when navigating to a screen with a condition

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a login screen and screens after the login, there other screens fetch data. But if something wrong happends with the api i did so it returns the user back to the login after he enters the app if there is a problem with the api for example reponse.statuscode == 401 etc.

```
late Response response2;
String? basicAuth;
TextEditingController phoneNumberController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

Future<Response> fetchWorkingLocationData(BuildContext context) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var authorization = prefs.getString('authorization');
  var url = 'https://dev.api.wurk.skyver.co/api/v1/projects';
  basicAuth = 'Basic ' +
      base64Encode(
        utf8.encode('${phoneNumberController.text}:${passwordController.text}'),
      );
  response2 = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(url),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'authorization': authorization ?? basicAuth.toString()
    },
  );
  if (response2.statusCode == 401 || response2.statusCode == 403) {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginScreen()));
    prefs.remove('authorization');
// here i want to show the toast message after it sends the user to login, and the message is: User data was changed.
  }
  print(response2.statusCode);

  return response2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to show a `SnackBar` with your message

```dart
...
prefs.remove('authorization');
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
  content: Text('User data was changed'),
),);
```

You might have to wrap your `Scaffold` in a `ScaffoldMessenger`, but other than that this should work just fine.

More info on how to work with the `SnackBar` can be found in the docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/snackbars

Comment: You can alternatively use the `fluttertoast` [package](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast), but the material design specifications advise the use of a SnackBar, I think.

Comment: the function is not inside the build method

Comment: But it is called from some `onPressed` or similar in the build method, right? You should then be able to pass the `BuildContext` to this function as an argument.

Comment: ok, im gonna update you on what happenes

Answer (score 0):

use snackbar code there

as

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Yay! this is my message!')));
```